# Can't get child div IDs within each parent div/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

When I try to get child div IDs within each parent div/class I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined".  I am using this javascript with scriptaculous so I have turned off the "$" shortcut.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="group1" class="section">
     <h3 class="handle"><input type="hidden" name="groupName1" value="MyGroup1">MyGroup1</h3>

    <div id="item_73548" class="lineitem">item a</div>
    <div id="item_73386" class="lineitem">item b</div>
    <div id="item_73163" class="lineitem">item c</div>
</div>
<div id="group2" class="section">
     <h3 class="handle"><input type="hidden" name="groupName2" value="MyGroup2">MyGroup2</h3>

    <div id="item_73548" class="lineitem">item d</div>
    <div id="item_73386" class="lineitem">item e</div>
    <div id="item_73163" class="lineitem">item f</div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$.noConflict();
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

var groups = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
    var sectionID = section.id;

    var j = 0;

    jQuery.each(jQuery("#" + sectionID + " .lineitem"), function () {

        groups[i][j] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        j++;

    });

}

console.log(groups);
```

The output should be:

```
groups[0][0]="item_73548";
groups[0][1]="item_73386";
groups[0][2]="item_73163";
groups[1][0]="item_73548";
groups[1][1]="item_73386";
groups[1][2]="item_73163";
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qy9dB/3/

Comment: Why are you mixing native DOM access and jQuery? Get your sections using jQuery.forEach and then do a selector on each jQuery section object to get your div children `$('.lineitem', this).attr('id');`

Comment: Agreed, this is a small section of a much larger legacy script written in pure javascript using the scriptaculous library.  So I'm just using jQuery on the sections I've changed.  I wish I had time to rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that `groups[i]` is setup as an array before you try and add 2nd level elements to the array.

```
$.noConflict();
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

var groups = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
    var sectionID = section.id;

    groups[i] = [];

    var j = 0;

    jQuery.each(jQuery("#" + sectionID + " .lineitem"), function () {

        groups[i][j] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        j++;

    });

}

console.log(groups);
```